# Sequence of functions uniformly differentiable at a point?

Tags: derivatives, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of functions differentiable at $x_0$. Let

$r_{n}(h,x_0) = f_n(x_0+h)  - f_n(x_0) - f'_n(x_0)h $

We know that for any fixed $n$, $r_n(h,x_0) = o(|h|)$ as $h \to 0$ from the existence of the derivative at $x_0$.

I'm trying to find a property in the literature that I would call "uniform differentiability at a point", and that I would define as

$sup_n|r_n(h,x_0)| = o(|h|)$

That is, the whole sequence of functions has remainders that converge uniformly to zero at $x_0$.

Has such a property been studied before? If so, what is known about it?

I searched for more information but I can only find the term "uniform differentiability" when the uniformity is with respect to $x$ instead of $n$.

EDIT: [Found a paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1366030637) that describes "uniformly strongly differentiable" sequences of functions. It's analogous to my definition but for strong differentiability.

Comment: You should weaken that condition to $\limsup_n$. Using $\sup_n$ is too strong.

Comment: Why would I do that? The sequence $\{f_n\}$ is arbitrary, and is not known to converge.

Comment: $sup$ is the maximum over all elements. if $f_1$ is slow in its convergence, it hides the behavior of all the later functions. $\lim sup$, which does not require convergence of the sequence (that is the "limsup", not the limit of the sup), is about how the tail of the sequence and is not bothered by any irregularities along the way, as long as they occur only a finite number of times. This generally gives you enough strength to prove what you need, but allows you to apply the results much more widely - less work to do to show a particular sequence meets the requirements.

Comment: I'd rather not exclude $f_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform equi-countinuity of the sequence $\{f_n'\}$ is a sufficient condition since
$$
f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)-hf'_n(x)=h\big(\,f_m'(\xi)-f_n'(x)\big)
$$
for some $\xi\in(x,x+h)$.

We say that $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$, such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$
$$
|x-y|<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |g_n(x)-g_n(y)|<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid continuity assumptions around $x_0$  and the mean-value theorem by using the Peano form of the remainder, but it doesn't seem possible to go without these assumptions when $\{f_n\}$ is an infinite sequence.